# Default validation message does not render properly on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a dialog for the user to add things, I was quite chuffed with using the in-built HTML5 framework validation, and the desktop works very well (doesn't handle accessibility well though as it does not scale when you want zoom of 200%).

When I test on a mobile device, the styling has all gone weird with the borders. This didn't happen when I zoomed the desktop or resized the window to simulate a mobile device, so I don't think it's my styling that's done it.

I think it has something to do with the browsers implementation of html5 validation as you can see from the smaller screenshot below the alert overhangs the browser boundaries.

Because I cannot replicate this on my desktop, I am unable to debug this and inspect the elements to track the CSS.

Any idea what I've broken?

[image: android screenshot] [image: desktop overflow screenshot]

Comment: I assume it's caused by `ui-input-text` div wrapping `input`.

Comment: Can you replicate in an emulator (e.g. Ripple) on your desktop? Then you could inspect the CSS.

Comment: I don't have ripple and can't download a version for my mac yet, but I cannot replicate this on the desktop version of chrome. The desktop version does show an interesting thing though that it seems to be browser implemented. On a mobile device this could manifest as a CSS issue.

Comment: @Omar, I have tried several iterations of `.ui-input-text input` trying to set the background red with the important marker and I don't seem to be able to make this change any.

Comment: Note that `required` attribute isn't supported by all mobile browsers. Check this link http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html